# On 16.04, How config Integrated Graphics, not Nvidia GPU?

Tags: nvidia, graphics, cuda

I am running ubuntu 16.04 on a desktop which has an nvidia gpu chip.

```
dan@redt:~ $ 
dan@redt:~ $ cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="16.04 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 16.04 LTS"
VERSION_ID="16.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=xenial
dan@redt:~ $ 
dan@redt:~ $
```

Also the desktop has integrated graphics:

```
dan@redt:~ $ 
dan@redt:~ $ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Integrated Graphics (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI #1 (rev 31)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SATA controller [AHCI mode] (rev 31)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f1)
00:1c.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #7 (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PMC (rev 31)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H HD Audio (rev 31)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SMBus (rev 31)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 134e (rev a2)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 (rev 81)
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
dan@redt:~ $ 
dan@redt:~ $ 
dan@redt:~ $
```

How do I configure this host so it uses 'Sky Lake Integrated Graphics' to control the graphics?

I want to use the GPU for Nvidia Cuda calculations instead of graphics.

Comment: Do `glxinfo | grep "OpenGL"`. If you see "Intel Open Source Technology Center", then you are already using integrated graphics.

Comment: Well what do you have the desktop connected to the monitor with? On desktops usually on the motherboard there are outputs for the integrated graphics while the nvidia card has its own outputs on the graphics card itself. To have the interface appear on your monitor you need to plug it into the graphics you are using.